# Automatically resizing textarea in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

I found the following very simple way to automatically adjust a textarea to the text height in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/gLhCk/:

```js
function expandTextarea(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        this.style.height = 0;
        this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }, false);
}

expandTextarea('txtarea');
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;  
}

textarea {
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:5px;
  height:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  width:96%;
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;    
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtarea" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Statusku..."></textarea>
```

However, I'm using bootstrap in my project and this introduces problems.

1. The textarea is only 4px high instead of 16. It seems like bootstrap changes the way margins and paddings and heights work?
2. When hitting enter, the text is jumping up and down, which is irritating to the eye.

I tried to delete all bootstrap classes in the HTML inspector of my browser but the problem was still there. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Here's the code when bootstrap's CSS is added:

```js
function expandTextarea(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        this.style.height = 0;
        this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }, false);
}

expandTextarea('txtarea');
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;  
}

textarea {
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:5px;
  height:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  width:96%;
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;    
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">



<textarea id="txtarea" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Statusku..."></textarea>
```

Comment: I've been looking for how to autoexpand textarea too. I'm doing a python tutorial and using pycharm. Where do I put in all this stuff? >.> my code so far is:
<div class="form-group">

            <label for="content">Content</label>

            <textarea id="content" class="form-control" name="content" spellcheck="false"
                      placeholder="Write stuff here ..."></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Publish</button>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, it gave me valuable insights into what I had to change. In the end, a bit more padding-bottom in the css did the trick.

```js
function expandTextarea(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        this.style.height = 0;
        this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }, false);
}

expandTextarea('txtarea');
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;  
}

textarea {
  /* margin:0px 0px; this is redundant anyways since its specified below*/
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:25px; /* increased! */
  /* height:16px; */
  /* line-height:16px; */
  width:100%; /* changed from 96 to 100% */
  display:block;
  /* margin:0px auto; not needed since i have width 100% now */
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">



<textarea id="txtarea" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Statusku..."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

replace `height` with `min-height`

```
textarea {
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:5px;
  min-height:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  width:96%;
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;    
}
```

Comment: okay this seems to be working for problem one. Do you also have an answer for problem two? ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the input box to automatically adapt to the text height. You can try not to use input / textarea but to use div like that:

```
<div contenteditable="true" aria-multiline="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it also is really nice if one wants editable table cells :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, bootstrap textarea with autosize until I found the solution here, [textarea-autosize lib by javierjulio](https://github.com/javierjulio/textarea-autosize), It works for me, you can try it.

```
textarea.textarea-autosize {
  height: 2.25rem;
  min-height: 2.25rem;
  resize: none;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

textarea.textarea-autosize.form-control-lg {
  height: 3.75rem;
  min-height: 3.75rem;
}

textarea.textarea-autosize.form-control-sm {
  height: 2rem;
  min-height: 2rem;
}
```

For sample of this library you can visit this page [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/djibe89/bofcrp8v/). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

getbootstrap.com said:

```
<div class="overflow-auto">...</div>
<div class="overflow-hidden">...</div>
```

hidden seemed to do the job just fine  ie.. remove the overflow.
As always, you must be inside

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important to overwrite bootstrap property.

```
textarea {
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:5px;
  height:16px !important;
  line-height:16px;
  width:96%;
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;    
}
```

Comment: did you try this? doesn't seem to have the desired effect to me?

Comment: one more thing you can do, remove textarea property from css and add class form-control into textarea.  <textarea class="form-control" id="txtarea" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Statusku..."></textarea>

Comment: still jumping and still the wrong height. also !important fixes it to 16, but I want it to resize.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function expandTextarea(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        this.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        this.style.height = 0;
        this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }, false);
}

expandTextarea('txtarea');
```

```css
body {
  padding:50px;  
}

textarea {
  margin:0px 0px;
  padding:5px;
  height:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  width:96%;
  display:block;
  margin:0px auto;    
}



<textarea id="txtarea" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Statusku..."></textarea>
```

Comment: killing a fly with a sniper rifle... more damage than profit.. might result in unintended effects

Answer (score -4):

it is more simpliest, just add a propertie like rows="10", you can show as meny as you want.